# changing UIButton.textLabel width at runtime

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to change some UIButton.textLabel.text at runtime to reflect program states. Specifically, the button is used to make a selection from a list, and the result should be pasted onto the button. It is easy enough to change the text itself, but if the text is longer than the original title text I put in there in Interface Builder, the new text is truncated to fit into the space that the original text occupied.

I found a workaround: I use a long string of spaces as the original title, which seems to "reserve" the space for longer strings later. But that seems kludgy. Anyone know if there is some sort of setting in IB, or a call I can make to force resizing when I change the text?

Comment: `-[UILabel sizeToFit]` ?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this,

[UIButton setTitle:@"ANY TEXT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];